# How to see if variable is < or equal to 0

Tags: javascript, html

I need to see if variable is < or equal to 0

Heres my code im working with.
theres other behind the scenes stuff to do with lives but all i need to know
is how to see its value (more below)

```
function beginCountup() {
    var display = document.getElementById("display"),
        i = 0;

    intervalID = setInterval(function () {
        display.textContent = ++i;
    }, 26);

    lives = lives - 1;
    var lcount = document.getElementById('lives')
    lcount.innerHTML = lives;
}
```

So i need to see if lives < or equal to 0 if so i need it to target ElementById('lives')
and make it say game over thanks!

Comment: if (lives <= 0) { ... }  Simple conditional test

Comment: That ^ Also `lives = lives - 1;` can be written as `lives -= 1;`, `--lives;` or `lives--;`.

Comment: That * Also if you're sure your counter will not skip a count ;) you can use `if(!lives){ // if === 0`

Comment: google `javascript if`

Answer (score 2):

Simple if statement

```
if(lives<=0){
    document.getElementById("lives").innerHTML="Game Over!"
}
```

Comment: Thanks i knew it was simple my brains all over the place atm :-)